# Valgrind error for SIGINT during pthread_cond_wait

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm running the following code in Valgrind (`valgrind --tool=helgrind ./program_name`).

```
void cleanup(void *mutex) {
    pthread_mutex_t *m = (pthread_mutex_t *)mutex;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(m);
}

void function() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&some_struct.some_mutex);
    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup, &some_struct.some_mutex);
    while (some_condition) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&some_struct.some_cond, &some_struct.some_mutex);
    }
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
}
```

It runs `function`, but if I send SIGINT immediately after the function is run, this happens (edit: on SIGINT, the thread running `function` gets canceled):

```
==3744== Thread #4 unlocked a not-locked lock at 0x30D300
==3744==    at 0x483A1D4: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==3744==    by 0x10994F: cleanup (some_program.c:193)
==3744==    by 0x1099A7: function (some_program.c:199)
```

Edit: I modified the code to initialize the mutex as such:

```
pthread_mutexattr_init(&some_struct.err_chk_attr);
pthread_mutexattr_settype(&some_struct.err_chk_attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK);
pthread_mutex_init(&some_struct.some_mutex, &client_control.err_chk_attr);
```

And added this to `cleanup`:

```
if (pthread_mutex_unlock(m)) {
    write(2, "flag\n", 6);
}
```

Running this does not print the flag inside or outside valgrind. When I run my code inside valgrind, I still get the valgrind error, but no printout. This seems contradictory, because if I were unlocking a mutex that's already unlocked, I would expect a valgrind error and a printout. As a sanity check, I confirmed that the mutex attribute catches the unlocking and unlocked mutex error by adding another `pthread_mutex_unlock(m)` immediately after this one with a similar print statement. This gives both a valgrind error and a print statement.

Comment: suggest change: `write(2, "flag\n", 6);` to `write(2, "flag\n", sizeof( "flag\n" ));`

Comment: The posted question is about a run-time problem.  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you to debug it.

Comment: Is the thread's cancellation type asynchronous or deferred?  Do note this clause from the pthread_cond_wait man page: "[...] When the cancelability enable state of a thread is set to PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, a side effect of acting upon a cancellation request while in a condition wait is that the mutex is (in effect) re-acquired before calling the first cancellation cleanup handler. [...]".  It's possible that Valgrind might be failing to correctly emulate that behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You're mistaken about what happens, but you're also missing relevant code: particularly, what the signal handler does. I'm assuming there is a signal handler, since otherwise the signal would either be causing your program to terminate, or would have to have been ignored or blocked, in which case nothing would happen when you try to interrupt it.

Receipt of `SIGINT` does not cause `pthread_cond_wait` to return with the mutex left unlocked. In fact it doesnt' cause `pthread_cond_wait` to return at all, even if the signal handler is installed as an interrupting (not `SA_RESTART`) one, since `pthread_cond_wait` is forbidden from failing due to `EINTR`. Of course it's still possible that `pthread_cond_wait` returns spuriously at any time, but whenever it returns, no matter what the reason, the mutex must always be acquired again (internally, by the implementation) before that happens.

It's likely that the cause of your problem is in other code you haven't shown us. Indeed, you've added:

> edit: on `SIGINT`, the thread running function gets canceled

This is not sufficient to diagnose the problem, but suggests that you might be calling `pthread_cancel` from the signal handler. If so, that's almost certainly your problem. `pthread_cancel` is not async-signal-safe, and thus the only way you can call it from a signal handler is to ensure that the handler can only run in a context where it's not interrupting another function that's not async-signal-safe. This would involve either having a dedicated signal handling thread with the signal blocked in all other threads (but then it's easier to just use `sigwaitinfo` to receive it), or blocking and unblocking the signal dynamically so that it's blocked whenever you're calling non-AS-safe functions.

Since you're only seeing the problem with valgrind, it's likely that either valgrind perturbs things so that the signal handler ends up running in a different thread (which one it runs in is unspecified among the set that are candidates for receiving it), or that the resulting undefined behavior just happens not to have a visible manifestation (yet) without valgrind running.